# Подключение пула к файлам

Tags: mysql, node.js

У меня есть пул подключения содержащий следующий код:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2')

function createPool() {
    const pool = mysql.createPool({
        connectionLimit: 5,
        host: process.env.HOST,
        user: process.env.USER,
        password: process.env.PASSWORD, 
        database: process.env.DATABASE
    })
}

exports.pool = createPool
```

Пытаюсь подключить данный пул к файлу откуда пытаюсь сделать простой запрос к базе:

```
const path = require('path')
let filePath = path.join(__dirname, '/database/pool')
const pool = require(filePath)

let query = 'SELECT Count(*) FROM users'

pool.query(query, (err, results)=>{
    console.log(err)
    console.log(results)
})
```

Вроде все логично, но падает ошибка: `TypeError: pool.query is not a function`. Аналогичная ошибка падает и при выполнении `pool.execute`. Как это можно исправить?

Структура следующая

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: распечатайте __dirname, process.cwd(), покажите картинкой структуру каталогов

Comment: __dirname возвращает путь до папки js, а process.cwd() путь до корня проекта

Comment: тут три ошибки: 1) в pool.js в функция createPool не возвращает ничего; 2) в pool.js вы экспортируете функцию, а нужно экспортировать результат её вызова, `module.exports = createPool()`; 3) подключение: абсолютный путь тут не нужен, замените на относительный путь `const pool = require('./pool')` и будет работать.

Comment: Да так работает, спасибо